# string capturing before / symboal

Tags: c#, string

Lets say I have a string:

```
string a = "abc&dcg / foo / oiu";
```

now i would like the output to be

```
"abc&dcg"
```

i have tried:

```
string output= a.Substring(a.IndexOf('/'));
```

but it returns the last part not the first part

I have tried `trim()` as well, but doesn't provide me with the results.

Comment: thanks for the quick anwser guys, but lets say between the g and / there is a space, how do i eleminate that with the same one line of code? thanks

Comment: thanks for the anwsers guys, and TrimEnd(' '); eliminate the last white space of the output

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string output;
if (a.IndexOf('/')>=0) { output = a.Split('/')[0].Trim() };
```

This wil prevents error case `a` doesn't contains any `/`

Comment: I have changed to `Trim()`since replace would replace all spaces, including that ones separating the words before `/`(if exists)

Comment: what if is something like this abc def & sdf / jfdkjf , and i would like to just get abc def & sdf, which eliminates the last space only, thanks!!

Comment: It will returns abc def & sdf. Isn't right? Observe that I perceived this could happen with `replace` and changed my answer to `Trim`

Comment: i think trimend() would do the trick

Comment: yah it did, thanks for the help

Comment: The difference between trim and trimend is that the first removes spaces from begin and end, while the second onle removes the spaces from the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string result = a.Split('/')[0].Trim();
```

The split operation will give you the 3 substrings separated by '/' and you can choose whichever ones you want by specifying the index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 string a = "abc&dcg / foo / oiu";
 string output = a.Substring(0, a.IndexOf("/"));
 Console.WriteLine(output);
```

It will show

```
abc&dcg
```